# Como puedo medir la distancia recorrida luego de apretar un boton en android?

Tags: android, gps

He implementado varios métodos para poder sumar la distancia recorrida ya sea caminando corriento, etc... todo con LocationListener. Estoy implementandolo sobre api +23 manejando los permisos.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("Location", "lat: " + location.getLatitude());
    Log.i("Location", "lng: " + location.getLongitude());
    String str="Location"+ location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(this,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

Pero necesito hacerlo luego de pulsar un botón iniciar. He seguido varias preguntas de SO, como esta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808622/cant-get-current-location-android-on-location-changed por ejemplo. Y algunas mas pero no he dado con la solución.

---

Edicion:

Luego de algunas sugerencias como las de abajo hice esto:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.bIniciar) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        setOldLoc(location);

    }
}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        setNewLoc(location);
        distance=getDistance()+(getOldLoc().distanceTo(getNewLoc()));
        setDistance(distance);
        setOldLoc(location);

    distancia.setText("Recorrido:"+String.valueOf(getDistance()));


}
```

Pero aunque el dispositivo esté detenido sigue variando las coordenadas en " OnLocationChanged".

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Cual es la duda? ya puedes guardar las ubicaciones? para obtener la distancia recorrida tienes que obtener la distancia de punto a punto y vas sumando.

Comment: @diegoveloper la duda es como iniciar el guardado desde el evento onclick de un botón, la distancia entre dos puntos la calculo con distanceto y luego sumaría eso, el.problema es que no se a que llamar desde el onclick, a la última location conocida? La suma de las distancias las hago dentro de onlocationchanged()?

Answer (score 0):

Desde el `onClick` debes llamar a :

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( ...
```

Para que inicies la obtención de la ubicación conforme vas cambiando de posición, entonces dentro de  `onLocationChanged` vas guardando la latitud y longitud y calculando la distancia de acuerdo a los puntos.

Revisa los parámetros del método [requestLocationUdpates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)) , hay un parámetro que es el `minDistance`, ahí le puedes poner una distancia mínima en metros para que pueda entrar al `onLocationChanged`

Comment: Es lo que estoy haciendo ahora pero tengo el problema de que estando el celular quieto, la Location sigue cambiando.Alguna idea?

Comment: ya actualicé mi resspuesta

Comment: Ahora me encuentro con otro problema onLocationChanged(Location location ) en la variable location no tengo la misma precision que en             location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); entonces la primer medicion de distancia ya me da culquier resultado.

Comment: tu primera ubicación ponle location = null , y cuando hagas la validacion, verifica que sea != null para que compares.